# How to call a stored procedure from Informatica cloud data integration?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud

I am new learner in Informatica cloud data integration. Currently I am trying to convert `SSIS ETL` to Informatica.

While conversion, at one point I need to call a SQL Server stored procedure inside Informatica data integration which mainly update some data in tables. I tried many things but not getting success.

Can anyone have any idea how we can call a SQL Server stored procedure using informatica cloud data integration?

Comment: you should use sql transformation and then call the procedure from there

Comment: This  sql transformation available in informatica cloud data integration?

Comment: see here:  https://network.informatica.com/videos/1213

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the SQL transformation.

refer to the following link : [network.informatica.com/videos/1213](https://network.informatica.com/videos/1213)

Accept this as the right answer if it helped you. This will help people in future

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a pre- or post processing script and call it from the native system as part of an integration. If this is for Application Integration then call as a command (and enable commands).

HTH

Scott S Nelson

Comment: Thanks for you input Scott. but my result achieved by SQL transformation.